# How to compare variables if not http 200 status

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, comparison

I have currently written a webscraping where I compare two values to see if there has been any increased value from previous request compare to new request.

```
import json
import re
import time
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional, List

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


@dataclass
class Product:
    name: Optional[str]
    price: Optional[str]
    image: Optional[str]
    sizes: List[str]

    @staticmethod
    def get_sizes(doc: BeautifulSoup) -> List[str]:
        pat = re.compile(
            r'^<script>var JetshopData='
            r'(\{.*\})'
            r';</script>$',
        )
        for script in doc.find_all('script'):
            match = pat.match(str(script))
            if match is not None:
                break
        else:
            return []

        data = json.loads(match[1])
        return [
            variation
            for get_value in data['ProductInfo']['Attributes']['Variations']
            if get_value.get('IsBuyable')
            for variation in get_value['Variation']
        ]

    @classmethod
    def from_page(cls, url: str) -> Optional['Product']:
        with requests.get(url) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        name = doc.select_one('h1.product-page-header')
        price = doc.select_one('span.price')
        image = doc.select_one('meta[property="og:image"]')

        return cls(
            name=name and name.text.strip(),
            price=price and price.text.strip(),
            image=image and image['content'],
            sizes=cls.get_sizes(doc),
        )


def main():
    product = Product.from_page("https://shelta.se/sneakers/nike-air-zoom-type-whiteblack-cj2033-103")

    previous_request = product.sizes

    while True:
        product = Product.from_page("https://shelta.se/sneakers/nike-air-zoom-type-whiteblack-cj2033-103")

        if set(product.sizes) - set(previous_request):
            print("new changes on the webpage")
            previous_request = product.sizes

        else:
            print("No changes made")

        time.sleep(500)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem I am facing is that there is a scenario where the product can be taken down. For example if I now have found sizes`['US 9,5/EUR 43', 'US 10,5/EUR 44,5']` and the webpage gets taken down by the admin where it returns 404. After few hours they re-add back the webpage and add again the values `['US 9,5/EUR 43', 'US 10,5/EUR 44,5']`- That would not print the value we already had it before on our previous valid request.

I wonder what would be the best way to print out the values if a webpage returns from 404 back to 200 (even if they add the same value?)

Comment: Wouldn't 404 raise exception in `response.raise_for_status()`?

Comment: @aaron that is true. That would have raised it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `response.raise_for_status()` is incorrect in this case. That will simply raise an exception if the website returns a 404, 500 or similar, exiting your program. change out `response.raise_for_status()` with:

```py
if response.status_code is not 200:
    return cls(None,None,None,None)
```

**EDIT** as i misinterpreted the question:

An empty product will now be returned if an error occurred. The only check required now is if the sizes has changed.

```py
def main():
    url = "https://shelta.se/sneakers/nike-air-zoom-type-whiteblack-cj2033-103"

    previous_product = Product.from_page(url) 
    while True:
        product = Product.from_page(url)
        
        if not product.sizes == previous_product.sizes:
            print("new changes on the webpage")
        else:
            print("No changes made")
        
        previous_product = product
        time.sleep(500)
```

`previous_product` has been moved outside. In this exact case, it does not matter, but it improves readability.

The use of `set(...) - set(...)` has been removed as it does not catch when something has been removed from the website, only when something is added. If something is first removed and then re-added, it would be have been caught by your program either.

Comment: Hi! Seems like very valid point! However I do have some concern so e.g. if our latest valid requests returns `['US 9,5/EUR 43', 'US 10,5/EUR 44,5']` and then the page goes 404 for x amount of hours and then gets re-added back with the sizes of the same: `['US 9,5/EUR 43', 'US 10,5/EUR 44,5']`. That wouldnt say "new changes on the website" right? Wouldnt see need to set the sizes to empty sets so whenever they add it back then it would print?

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie Yes, that is correct, but I thought that is exactly what you wanted to avoid? Did I misread the question?

Comment: I believe it might be me who didn't questioned correctly but basically what I wrote before what I was looking for. That it should print out if it goes from 404 to 200 even if its same "sizes" that gets uploaded once again. If that make sense?

Comment: Hi again! Just saw the edit and you are amazing! I was thinking something similar but didnt thought I could do cls(None.....) that is very clever as well with the way to check for theif not ... Thank you so much :)